# For $x,y,z,1$ in some group, do the algebraic manipulations on $xyz = 1$ that preserve truth and group membership describe an algebraic strcuture?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider $xyz = 1$, where $x,y,z,1$ are elements of some group $G$. There are a number of algebraic manipulations we can perform on this equation which preserve the truth of the equation as well as the fact that all members of the equation pertain to $G$:

- $(xy)z = z(xy)$ or $x(yz) = (yz)x$ on a single side of the equation, from the group definition of an inverse element (these describe a cyclic group of order 3)
- Left and right multiplication by $x,y,z$ on both sides of the equation.

Do these describe any sort of well known algebraic structure? I'd like to formalize a proof that, if we are within a group, there is no way to show that $xyz = 1$ implies $yxz = 1$ if we only have right multiplication or commutativity of inverses, requiring left multiplication (i.e., if we want to construct $yxz = 1$ from $xyz = 1$, there is no way to do so without left multiplication, requiring $xyz = 1 \implies xyzx = x \implies yxz = 1$).

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  In a group, left inverses are also right inverses, so $xyz=1$ *does* imply that $yzx=1$.  Were you thinking of a weaker structure than a group?

Comment: @lulu sorry, I meant $yxz = 1$. I've edited the post

Comment: Well, left inverses are unique so if you had both equalities you'd have to have $xy=yx$.

Comment: @lulu we don't know whether the group is abelian, and we don't know whether we have $yzx = 1$, if we start from $xyz = 1$ (thanks for the comment, I will clarify this in my post)

Comment: If your objective is to show that $xyz = 1$ does not imply $yxz = 1$, all you need to do is find a counterexample. Clearly, you need to take $G$ to be a non-abelian group. The smallest non-abelian group is the dihedral group of order $6$, try to find your $x, y, z$ here.

Comment: My point was that, given $xyz=e$, then we also have $yxz=e$ if and only if $xy=yx$.

Comment: @Haran right! but I was interested in seeing if there was a way to formulate a proof without a counterexample, using the available "algebraic moves" if you will. Furthermore, I want to prove that a specific "algebraic move" is needed, left multiplication

Comment: Unhelpful answer: they describe the normal subgroup $H$ of the free group $F = \langle x, y, z\rangle$ generated by $xyz$. So all you need to do(!) is work out whether the image of $yxz$ in $F/H$ is trivial or not. Unfortunately, this is in general a very hard problem, and this reframing doesn't give us any extra ways to think about it or methods to solve it.

Comment: Then you should probably take @lulu 's suggestion. As they say, xyz = 1 and yxz = 1 is equivalent to saying that xy is the inverse of z and yx is the inverse of z respectively. This is equivalent to $xy = yx$, which is not necessary for groups. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Haran Thanks for the contribution! I'm specifically looking to see whether there are algebraic structures that can describe equation construction. But I see what lulu and you are saying, very appreciated! At Billy: thanks for the comment!

Comment: Haran, before you refer to @lulu as a "he", you need to know that.  Please use "they" when you have no clue.  Women are increasingly present in math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following answer is essentially a summary of the ideas posted in the comments.

We are given that $x, y, z$ are three elements of some group $G$ such that $xyz = 1$, and we want to show that there is no way in which we can conclude the statement $yxz = 1$. Generally, the best (and simplest) way to show that $A \nRightarrow B$ is by showing that there $A \land (\lnot B)$ is consistent. In our context, this means finding a group where $xyz = 1$ but $yxz \neq 1$. One can do this by taking
$$G = D_6 = \langle r, s \mid r^3 = s^2 = 1, rs = sr^{-1} \rangle$$
Letting $x = s$, $y = r$, and $z = sr$, we have:

- $xyz = s \cdot r \cdot sr = (sr)^2 = 1$
- $yxz = r \cdot s \cdot sr = sr^{-1}sr = r^2 \neq 1$

Observe that the conditions $xyz = 1$ and $yxz = 1$ are equivalent to $z^{-1} = xy$ and $z^{-1} = yx$. Now, we can see that $z$ is really a dummy variable here since every group element has a unique inverse, so we are essentially asking whether $xy = yx$. This is not true for non-commutating elements in non-abelian groups (like the values of $x$ and $y$ chosen in the counterexample above).

An algebraic viewpoint for the same is the free group idea suggested in the comments. The 'general' conditions satisfied by $x, y, z$ is captured by the free group $F = \langle x, y, z \rangle$. The idea of a free group is that no two words are equal unless they must be due to the group axioms. A more rigorous way of saying this is a universal property. In our case, the universal property is the following: for all groups $G$ with elements $a, b, c$, there exists a unique group homomorphism $\varphi: F \to G$ such that $\varphi(x) = a$, $\varphi(y) = b$, $\varphi(z) = c$.

To make sense of the above definition, you must first show that there is indeed such a group $F$ with elements $x, y, z$. You will have to define the group of words in three variables and rigorously prove that it is a well-defined group (you'll require some induction on the length of words for showing the well-defined part, it's a little annoying). After showing the existence of such an $F$, you get uniqueness up to isomorphism for free because of the universal property.

Now, let's say that for all groups $G$ and elements $a, b, c$, we have $abc = 1 \implies cab = 1$. This must also be true for $\overline{x}, \overline{y}, \overline{z}$ in $F/N$, where $N$ is the minimal normal subgroup containing $xyz$ (the uniqueness of $N$ comes from taking the intersection of all normal subgroups containing $xyz$). This is equivalent to $zxy \in N$.

On the other hand, if $zxy \in N$, then we get $abc = 1 \implies cab = 1$ for any group $G$. This is because the universal property of $F$ yields a universal property of $F/N$: for every group $G$ with $a, b, c$ such that $abc = 1$, there is a unique group homomorphism $\psi: F/N \to G$ such that $\psi(\overline{x}) = a$, $\psi(\overline{y}) = b$, $\psi(\overline{z}) = c$. To prove this, consider the map $\varphi: F \to G$ given by the universal property of $F$ and prove that $N \leqslant \ker \varphi$.

In general, whenever you have some algebraic relations (say $abc = caba$), we can rewrite them as elements which equal the identity ($abca^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}c^{-1} = 1$), and consider the minimal normal subgroup $N$ in $F$ which contains these elements. Now, the question of whether some other new algebraic relation is implied by the previous ones is equivalent to asking whether $N$ contains the element corresponding to the new algebraic relation. In the example above, we indeed do have $zxy \in N$ since $zxy = z(xyz)z^{-1}$. Now, your question asks whether $yxz \in N$ for the same $N$. We know that the answer is no (because we know counterexamples that exist). Showing that $yxz \not \in N$ seems painful if we are only allowed to work in the free group context. You can think about this if you want. The moral is probably that free groups capture the implications of algebraic relations neatly, but this may neither be helpful nor the most simple idea practically.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!